# Imagine this scenario...customer calls sales rep and automatically customer details are on screen

Tags: ideas

Imagine this scenario...customer calls sales rep and automatically customer details are on screen.Can this be made possible? Has this been already been implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That thing is implemented with CTI integration. We have configured for multiple clients

Comment: Could you kindly tell what do we need for such integration?

Comment: You need to have CTI Adapter for the telephony system of the client.  http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005115&language=en_US

Comment: ok cool ! Best answer for quick answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce provides screen pop functionality via a CTI adapter. The recommended path is via an OpenCTI adapter, as detailed at:

https://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Open_CTI

In this case the integration is handled directly in the browser and there is no need to install any software on the sales reps computer.  There is also a legacy CTI toolkit that allows you to build an adapter that is installed locally, and this relies on an ActiveX component to communicate with the user's browser:

http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/CTI_Toolkit

both of the above wiki pages have demonstration adapters that pop a screen with information about the caller when a call is received.

There are a number of pre-built adapters for CTI systems on the app exchange:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/results?keywords=cti